# ASP.NET core app not consuming messages from RabbitMQ's queue if hosted on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

**Setup**

RabbitMQ on localhost, asp.net core app using masstransit lib on IIS which consumes events.

**Problem**

There are messages in RabbitMQ queue and my asp.net core app does not consume it when it is hosted on IIS, also, it is not visible as consumer in RabbitMQ Management's queue details. However it consumes messages and is visible as consumer when I "dotnet run" it or run it on IIS Express.

**Code**

*Startup.cs fragment*

```
...
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<EventConsumer>();

    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host("localhost", c =>
        {
            c.Username("username");
            c.Password("password");
        });
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("queue-name", e =>
        {
            e.ConfigureConsumer<EventConsumer>(context);
        });
    });
});

services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
...
```

*EventConsumer.cs*

```
public class EventConsumer : IConsumer<Event>
{
    private readonly ILogger<EventConsumer> _logger;
    
    public EventConsumer(ILogger<EventConsumer> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Event> context)
    {
        var message = context.Message;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for all responses.

Comment: When running under IIS, is `IHostedService` resolved from the container and started? That's how the bus is started, and the environment seems to be the only difference.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Should I create something like [link](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ConsoleService/blob/master/SampleService/MassTransitConsoleHostedService.cs) ? If so, why is it working correctly without that service when not running under IIS? I thought that `services.AddMassTransitHostedService();` does that work.

Comment: MassTransit does have its own, you don't need to create it. I'm suggesting that something about running under IIS is different causing it _not_ to run it.

Comment: Seems related to some IIS settings: https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/1465

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Thank you v.much, as you wrote, it was related to IIS settings. I changed "Preload enabled" to true and it immediately started to consume messages from queue.